# Movesense rescheduleTimer

Tags: movesense

There is a rescheduleTimer() in the movesense_device_lib.
None of the example projects using it as I can see.

startTimer() and stopTimer() is working as expected but rescheduleTimer() always return false and the timer is not rescheduled.

Anybody else tried this function with success?

Before asking the question I checked:

- mTimer != wb::ID_INVALID_TIMER
- mTimer is a valid running timer ID
- I tried both ResourceClient::rescheduleTimer() and ResourceProvider::rescheduleTimer()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get false from rescheduleTimer if:

- There are no more free timers in the TimerPool
- timerId is not an existing timer
- timer is not continuous (second parameter was false in startTimer call)
- you try to reschedule a timer owned by some other class

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense Team*

Comment: So I think it's not working for me because I'm using single shot timers (not continuous). Is this information is available in any public documentation and I was just searching wrong or is this some internal staff and you have some more internal documentation?

Comment: It's internal in the (3rd party) Whiteboard component that the Movesense sensor uses. However the ResourceClient.h file where the method is defined contains the following comment: 

"    *   Reschedules the continuous timer with a new period; The existing timer is stopped and restarted (but not deallocated).
    *
    *   Note: A timer message with the previous timer interval might have been queued before processing the rescheduling.
    *   and hence the first time might fire in period less than the new period."